# Lua script for redis transaction

Tags: lua, redis

> Is there a way to use MULTI & EXEC command in lua? If not how to perform >transaction using lua script

Comment: Why do you need this in lua, what is your scenario? Lua scripts are atomically executed, so while they run there is no other thread/process changing your data. You can think of it as only one redis command

Answer (score 8):

Lua scripts are atomically executed, so while they run there is no other thread/process changing your data (because Redis is single threaded). You can think of it as only one redis command. So you should be able to do with a simple Lua script whatever you wanted to put in transaction. 
 Also you can check [Redis Scripting and Transactions](http://redis.io/topics/transactions#redis-scripting-and-transactions)
where it is mentioned that it is a possibility that transactions support will be removed in the far future because they can be replaced by scripts only.